# Executing linux command with variable using python

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-2.7

I'm writing a python script which should give the string inside the .dll file and these files stored in directory. The script is

```
import sys
import os
def main():
     for lst in os.listdir("dir name"):
             print lst
             os.system("strings"+" "+lst)
if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

This code is listing the files of the directory but it is not executing the command, giving error

**strings: 'filename' no such file **

What is the issue with this script ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with filenames that contain spaces or other special characters.

You can try:

```
def quote(s):
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "'\\''") + "'"

def main():
     for lst in os.listdir("."):
          print lst
          os.system("strings " + quote(lst))
```

*PS with Python 3.3 (or greater), use [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) instead*